# apply a styles and theme to custom view (compound component) in styles.xml file

Tags: android-layout, android-custom-view, android-theme, android-styles

I would like to apply styles and use a theme in a custom view (compound component) from the `styles.xml` file.
I have not found any way to do it as I need.
I tried to use custom attributes, but these prevent me from passing my custom parameters to the constructor from the custom view.

Comment: Hello Fra, welcome to StackOverflow. First and foremost, you should post a little bit of the code "you have tried" so we can see what it is all about. In any case, *do not pass custom parameters to the constructor of a view* unless you are instantiating said view in code (Vs. just inflating XML). All those constructors (all 4) of a "View" are there for a reason.  Have you taken a look at -for example- [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/142-android-custom-view-tutorial)?

Comment: yes i am creating an instance of custom view from java code, i am not inflating from xml. I've already seen that tutorial, it doesn't help me. I didn't put code in because I believe there is no need. if we know custom views, views, styles and themes, I don't think we need the code to understand what I require.